# Hot water baseboard heat issue

Tags: plumbing

A baseboard was replaced in a bathroom remodel. The hot water from the boiler circles around the basement and pipes run out of it up to each room baseboard and an outgoing pipe returns water to the main for each room. The problem in the new bathroom...the incoming pipe is very hot but the outgoing near the bleeder is cold.  When I open the bleeder, after a few minutes the water from the bleeder becomes hot and so does the outgoing pipe.  After I close the bleeder, after a few minutes, the outgoing pipe is cold again.  What can be the problem?

Comment: There's likely a valve on supply and return for maintenance purposes (being able to close off one radiator). Ive also seen cases where the return valve instead of being manual is in fact a one way valve. It sounds like there's no flow tho, so it was hard to figure from what we can "see" of your system.

Comment: Do you have electric circulator pumps? From your description, it sounds like you have a gravity hot water system which does not use circulator pumps. If so, the density difference in water due to temperature is the driving force behind the water circulation. This also means that it is very sensitive to clogs. But without more info we can only guess. Can you get us the following information: how old is the house and heating system? Do you have electric circulator pumps? Are the pipes iron, copper or plastic? And lastly, can you post pictures?